# jquery selector contains equals sign

Tags: jquery, selector, equals, sign

I am using a jQuery selector to check for characters in href:

```
var param = "something";
$("a[href*="+param+"]").css("color", "red");
```

This works fine until "something" contains an = sign. Eg:

```
var param = "xkey=123";
$("a[href*="+param+"]").css("color", "red");
```

then I get no result.  Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the `=` character since it has a special meaning when used in a jQuery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Here's the full list of all characters that need to be escaped:

```
#;&,.+*~':"!^$[]()=>|/
```

Thus, you can use the following to escape the `param`:

```
param.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1')
```

From the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two backslashes: \.

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vGyys/)**.

Answer (score 3):

Quote the parameter:

```
$("a[href*='"+param+"']")
```

And if that's not enough (`param` may contain apostrophes) then escape them:

```
$("a[href*='"+param.replace(/'/g,"\\'")+"']")
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest solution that I suspect handles anything param can have.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `=` with `\\=`.

```
param = param.replace(/=/g, '\\\\=');
```

But there are other special chars you also need to escape in jQuery selector.

```
function escape(param) {
  return param.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\\\$1');
}
```

You also could use the `.filter` method.

```
$('a').filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr('href').indexOf(param) !== -1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is behaving that way becuase, at the end it will translate to ambiguous selector i.e. `$("a[href*=xkey=123]")` which indeed is invalid.

Escape the equal sign with `\\` infront and wrap the parameter part with a quote

```
var param = "xkey\\=123";
$("a[href*='"+param+"']").css("color", "red");
```

Comment: In this simple case, one or the other (quoting the parameter or escaping `=`) should work.

Comment: Yes, It is not necessary to parse the `param` for all the symbols. It is a simple case and should be kept as simple as possible.

Comment: Adding the quotes solved the problem without parsing but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can validate it like this:

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

foo - is the string;

```
if (! /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(foo)) {
    // Validation failed
}
```

**OR**

Escape it like this check:

```
if(your_string.indexOf('=') != -1){
  alert("equal found.");
}
```

then replace `=` with `\\=`